# How to use overloaded method (distinguish int or double)

Tags: java, overloading

I need to write a program that gets three numbers from the user, then passes those to an overloaded method (I have a `double` and `int`).

My question is how do I determine if it's an `int` or a `double`?

To get input I'm doing this:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
double number1 = input.nextDouble(); // read first double
double number2 = input.nextDouble(); // read second double
double number3 = input.nextDouble(); // read third double

MyMathOps MyMathOps = new  MyMathOps();
double result = MyMathOps.maximum( number1, number2, number3 ); 
System.out.println(result);
```

But what if they enter an `int`? I want to be able to determine this, and pass it to the `int` `maximum` method.

Comment: Of course, if were to enter `int`, they would automatically be promoted to `double`. Why do you need to determine which specific type is being entered? You should leave it to the compiler.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just treat all input as `double`, since you're supporting floating point inputs. It doesn't make sense to use `int` only sometimes just because the input happens to be an integer.

Comment: I think all `int` fit in a `double` (because it has 64bits). Would be a problem with a `float`. Objection withdrawn. +1

Answer (score 1):

number1, number2 and number3 are all declared as doubles. Even if they will contain an integer value, they will still be doubles (i.e. value 1.0).

If you want to know it the double value can also be represented as Integer value, you can convert the double to String:

```
String doubleString = Double.valueOf(number1)
```

splitting the string around the decimal dot:

```
String[] split = doubleString.split("\\.");
```

and then checking the decimal part to contain only zeroes:

```
boolean canBeInt = split[1].matches("0*");
```

If it is true, then you can run Integer.parseInt(split[0]) and get integer value (or just cast the original double to int).

Note this solution will not check for maximum integer value.

Comment: If you are going that way, better use `next()` or `nextLine()` and do the parsing on what the user really entered.

Comment: `String[] split = doubleString.split(".");` would not work until you escape the dot `.` like this `String[] split = doubleString.split("\\.");`

Answer (score 1):

Actually there are several methods to do that. For example you can use `input.next()` instead of `input.nextDouble()` and parse the returned String to check the data type (whether it is bounded by Integer's maximum and contains no fractional part)